# How subtract numerical ranges in SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

How I can subtract numerical ranges in SQL?

For example:

```
SELECT 01 AS 'BEGIN', 99 AS 'END'
EXCEPT
SELECT 01 AS 'BEGIN', 15 AS 'END'
```

expected result:

```
16 AS 'BEGIN', 99 AS 'END'
```

a more complete example:

```
COMPLETE
BEGIN ---- END
 01         99

EXTRACT
BEGIN ---- END
 15         30

RESULT
BEGIN ---- END
 01         14
 31         99
```

Its possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  What data are you starting with?

Comment: He wants to select 1 - 99, but remove 1 - 15 from the results

Comment: You will have to put some context into your question. The question is not clear but I think I understand what you are trying to do. The problem is that your example is over-simplified so that is no longer viable sql code. To get to an actual solution to your problem will require specifics, because there is no `EXCEPT` statement. Instead code will have to work out the required result. If you could provide a sample table structure we can try to help.

Comment: Does the range you want to subtract ever fall in the middle?

Comment: I edited the question, to see if I understand better

Comment: Do you XOR ranges? From your example it looks like you do. And the ranges seems to be discrete

Comment: @Turophile I totally agree that this question is extremely vague but there absolutely is EXCEPT in sql server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Expect it does not do anything close to that.  Op would have been better off using a operator name that was not valid

Comment: @Frisbee I realize it is nothing like they want. I did however want to point out that there is in fact an EXCEPT statement even though it doesn't solve the current issue.

Comment: The except was only to illustrate the logic of what is required, however implementation proposed below provides the expected result

Comment: @SeanLange And it is clear I am aware of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH Complete AS (
   SELECT 1 AS [BEGIN], 99 AS [END]
), Extract AS (
   SELECT 1 AS [BEGIN], 15 AS [END]
), FreeSpace AS (
   SELECT (SELECT [BEGIN] - 1 FROM Extract) AS [LEFT],
          (SELECT [END] + 1 FROM Extract) AS [RIGHT]
)
SELECT [BEGIN], [END]
FROM (
SELECT [BEGIN], (SELECT [LEFT] FROM FreeSpace) AS [END]
FROM Complete

UNION ALL 

SELECT (SELECT [RIGHT] FROM FreeSpace) AS [BEGIN], [END]
FROM Complete ) AS t
WHERE [END] >= [BEGIN]
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5184)

CTEs description:

- `Complete` is the interval from which we want another interval subtracted
- `Extract` is the interval to be extracted from `Complete`
- `FreeSpace` contains the *'free'* boundaries to the left and to the right of `Extract`

**Example:**

```
Extract:            15----------30
                  14              31  
FreeSpace: <------|               |------------->
```

Using values `14` and `31` from `FreeSpace` two possible non-overlapping intervals to the left and to the right of `Extract` are constructed.

Predicate:

```
WHERE [END] >= [BEGIN]
```

finally checks whether these two intervals really exist or not.